# How to convert JavaScript regex to c# regex?

Tags: javascript, c#

Let us say we have following regex code lines in Javascript:

```
.replace(/[\*\+\-=~><\"\?^\${}\(\)\:\!\/[\]\\\s]/g, '\\$&') // replace single character special characters

.replace(/\|\|/g, '\\||') // replace ||

.replace(/\&\&/g, '\\&&') // replace &&

.replace(/AND/g, '\\A\\N\\D') // replace AND

.replace(/OR/g, '\\O\\R') // replace OR

.replace(/NOT/g, '\\N\\O\\T'); // replace NOT
```

I am trying to translate these regex code lines to following C# Regex Expressions:

```
 public static String ReturnSanitizedString(string query)
    {
        String pattern1 = @"[\*\+\-=~><\""\?^\${ }\(\)\:\!\/[\]\\\s]"; // Replace the single character special characters. 
        String pattern2 = @"\|\|";
        String pattern3 = @"\&\&";
        String pattern4 = @"AND";
        String pattern5 = @"OR";
        String pattern6 = @"NOT";

        String replacement1 = "\\$&";
        String replacement2 = "\\||";
        String replacement3 = "\\&&";
        String replacement4 = "\\A\\N\\D";
        String replacement5 = "\\O\\R";
        String replacement6 = "\\N\\O\\T";

        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern1);
        string result1 = rgx.Replace(query, replacement1);

        Regex rgx2 = new Regex(pattern2);
        string result2 = rgx2.Replace(result1, replacement2);

        Regex rgx3 = new Regex(pattern3);
        string result3 = rgx3.Replace(result2, replacement3);

        Regex rgx4 = new Regex(pattern4);
        string result4 = rgx4.Replace(result3, replacement4);

        Regex rgx5 = new Regex(pattern5);
        string result5 = rgx5.Replace(result4, replacement5);

        Regex rgx6 = new Regex(pattern6);
        string finalResult = rgx6.Replace(result5, replacement6);

        return finalResult;
    }
```

The following sentence(this is the query):

```
"AND there! are? (lots of) char*cters 2 ^escape!"
```

Should be converted to this sentence after executing above code:

```
\A\N\D\ there\!\ are\?\ \(lots\ of\)\ char\*cters\ 2\ \^escape\!
```

I am not able to get this working, what am I doing incorrect in method above.

Comment: You're not changing the `rgx` object for each replace..... a.k.a you're using that same object for each replace...

Comment: Yes, thats right. I have changed it, but still I am not getting expected output. I am not sure where I am making a mistake.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982608/differences-between-c-sharp-and-javascript-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pattern3`, you have regex `\&\&|` which matches basically everything.
Just remove the last pipe like this and get what you want:

```
String pattern3 = @"\&\&";
```