# Using Jquery Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string in which i have unnecessary html tags(sample string is given below), i am using following regex in jquery for removing it and it is working:-

```
 var str = 'Dept : Dept Maths has <g class="gr_ gr_3 gr-alert gr_gramm gr_inline_cards gr_run_anim Grammar multiReplace" data-gr-id="30" id="30">a ''</g>DWE WQERT A1'' desc on school.'

 str= str.replace(/<\/?g[^>]*>/g, ""); //this is working
```

But i want to do it in C# code, i tried following :-

```
 var strRegex = Regex.Replace(str, "/<\\/?g[^>]*>/g", ""); // this is not working
```

But it didn't change anything.

how can i use same Regex in C# Code..any help please?

Comment: There are syntax differences, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982608/differences-between-c-sharp-and-javascript-regular-expressions - then, translate your expression from JS/jQuery to C# syntax. I am afraid there is no other way.

Comment: yes will refer that, Thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern (second parameter), you don't need the delimiters or flags. Just take off the beginning "/” and ending "/g"

Comment: Worked...Thank you..!