# Regex C# not working consistent with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have an issue about regex
This is my `string str = 'tât"` and I'm using regex for

- javascript:

  `str = str.replace(/[^\w\\-]+/g, '');  => result: tt`
- c#:

  `str = (new Regex(@"[^\w\\-]+")).Replace(str, ""); => result: tât`

I want to make result of C# like javascript, Please help me.

Thanks so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do all JavaScript regular expressions work in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343843/do-all-javascript-regular-expressions-work-in-net)

Answer (score 5):

The default .Net implementation of Regex is slightly different from the Javascript implementation.

Differences are described on on the [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#ecmascript-matching-behavior).

To use Javascript/ECMAscript rules in .Net:

```
   str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\w\\-]+", "", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a Alphabetic range like that:

```
str= (new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z0-9]+")).Replace(str, "");
```